# Custom permission level for creating groups

Tags: 2013, groups

I have been trying to create custom permission level which will allow user to create groups. But did not have any success.

What are the minimum permissions that need to be given so that if any user is assigned with this permission then he should be able to create groups?

Answer (score 1):

You must need the below bas permissions to perform SharePoint group creations and managing permission. Create a custom permission level with the following base permissions and assign it accordingly.

**List Permissions**

- Add Items  -  Add items to lists and add documents to document
  libraries.
- Edit Items  -  Edit items in lists, edit documents in document
  libraries, and customize Web Part Pages in document libraries.
- Delete Items  -  Delete items from a list and documents from a
  document library.
- View Items  -  View items in lists and documents in document
  libraries.
- Open Items  -  View the source of documents with    server-side file
  handlers.
- View Versions  -  View past versions of a list item or document.
- View Application Pages  -  View forms, views, and application pages. 
  Enumerate lists.

**Site Permissions**

- Manage Permissions  -  Create and change permission levels on the Web
  site and assign permissions to users and groups.
- Create Groups  -  Create a group of users that can be used anywhere
  within the site collection.
- Browse Directories  -  Enumerate files and folders in a Web site
  using SharePoint Designer and Web DAV interfaces.
- View Pages  -  View pages in a Web site.
- Enumerate Permissions  -  Enumerate permissions on the Web site,
  list, folder, document, or list item.
- Browse User Information  -  View information about users of the Web
  site.  Open  -  Allows users to open a Web site, list, or folder in
  order to access items inside that container.
- Edit Personal User Information  -  Allows a user to change his or her
  own user information, such as adding a picture.